# Relation between List<> and IEnumerable<> open type

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any relationship between the open types `List<>` and `IEnumerable<>`?

Example:

```
var type1 = typeof(List<>);
var type2 = typeof(IEnumerable<>);

//return false
type2.IsAssignableFrom(type1);
```

Is there any method to check the relationship between two open type, or the relationship only exist on closed type?

Comment: Relevant: [When does Type.FullName return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670901/in-c-when-does-type-fullname-return-null)

Comment: Note that each generic parameter is unique. That means `List<T(from List<T>)>` implement `IEnumerable<T(from List<T>)>` but not `IEnumerable<T(from IEnumerable<T>)>`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? If we knew what the initial problem you were trying to solve was, we may be able to offer other solutions that don't rely on comparing open generic types.

Comment: Sorry for the drastic edit, but I think only the problem expressed in the first 3 lines is the actually interesting part here. What you were trying to do with the rest of the code was very unclear and you would have had to explain that further as @Damien_The_Unbeliever stated.

Comment: @PetSerAl How to understand each generic parameter is unique? Do you mean type int in List<int> and IEnumerable<int> is "diffierent"?

Comment: `int` is not generic parameter `typeof(int).IsGenericParameter`. But generic parameter `T` declared in `List<>` is different from any other generic parameter, in particular, it is different from `T` declared in `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I try to convert a expression like this `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Typea>, Typea, bool>> expression1 = (values, value) => values.Contains(value);` to expression `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Typeb>, bool>>`, `TypeA` and `TypeB` are independent. I need convert `values` constant in expression1 to a new type `IEnumerable<Typeb>`, so I create a `List<Typeb>` instance to represent the `IEnumerable<Typeb>`, original expression collection can be any other generic interface. I want to check whether the values can be assignedd to `List<>`. I am curious about open type relation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although John Wu wrote up a nice answer about the differences between a type definition and actual types I don't think it fully answers the problem/question asked in the OP.

> Is there any method to check the relationship between two open type,
>   or the relationship only exist on closed type?

First of all, the relationship always exists; every `List<>` is always an `IEnumerable<>`, as you can see in the definition of the `List<T>` type:

`public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ...`

But this doesn't answer your second question, if there is a way to check if such a relationship exists between two types. You would think that the `IsAssignableFrom` method can be used to check for existence of a relationship between the type *open* types, but you can't. Why? Lets find out in the documentation of the `IsAssignableFrom` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_IsAssignableFrom_System_Type_):

> Type.IsAssignableFrom (Type c) Returns true if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. c and the current instance represent the same type.
> 2. c is derived either directly or indirectly from the current
>          instance. c is derived directly from the current instance if it
>          inherits from the current instance; c is derived indirectly from the
>          current instance if it inherits from a succession of one or more
>          classes that inherit from the current instance.
> 3. The current instance is an interface that c implements.
> 4. c is a generic type parameter, and the current instance represents
>          one of the constraints of c.
>
> and false if none of these conditions are true, or if c is null.

In your case, none of the above mentioned conditions will result in true as: (1) they are not the same type. (2) They cannot be derived from each other as they are open types: their generic type parameters are unknown (`unknown != unknown`). The `List<>` implements the closed `IEnumerable<T>` type and not the open `IEnumerable<>` type (3). They aren't generic type parameters (4).

To find out if two generic types have a relationship, you would need to inspect their `type definitions` (and their nested interfaces/base types) and validate that they have a relationship:

```
public static bool IsAssignableToOpenGenericType(Type givenType, Type genericType)
{
    var interfaceTypes = givenType.GetInterfaces();

    foreach (var it in interfaceTypes)
    {
        if (it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
            return true;
    }

    if (givenType.IsGenericType && givenType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
        return true;

    Type baseType = givenType.BaseType;
    if (baseType == null) return false;

    return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
}
```

[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616/how-to-detect-if-type-is-another-generic-type/1075059#1075059)

Will result in:

```
    var typ1 = typeof(List<>);
    var typ2 = typeof(IEnumerable<>);

    // true, List<>'s type definition contains an IEnumerable<>
    Console.WriteLine(IsAssignableToOpenGenericType(typ1, typ2));
    // false, IEnumerable<>'s type definition does not contain List<>
    Console.WriteLine(IsAssignableToOpenGenericType(typ2, typ1));
```

Answer (score 19):

`List<>` and `IEnumerable<>` are not types; they are [type definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564745/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generic-type-and-a-generic-type-definition). As such it doesn't really make sense to ask if one is assignable to the other. Neither can be assigned to. You can't declare a variable `List<> a = null`, for example-- you will get a compilation error "Unexpected use of an unbound generic name."

A type definition becomes a generic type when you specify the type parameter. At that point, it is a type and can be assigned to.  So for example `List<string>` can be assigned to `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you have a type definition in mind and you want to do a type-compatibility check, just use `<object>` (or a suitable type if there is a type constraint) instead of `<>`:

```
var type1 = typeof(List<object>);
var type2 = typeof(IEnumerable<object>);

//returns true
type2.IsAssignableFrom(type1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a brief check method. I can understand `type2.IsAssignableFrom(type1)` behavior. But do you mean two open generic type are independent or no relationship between them before they become closed type or bounded?

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean when you say "related?" Of course they have certain relationships, and not others.

Comment: A relationship such as inheritance, implimentation but not inheritance and implimentation. But I am not sure whether any kind relatioinship exist between **open generic type** themselves. @Jevgeni Geurtsen think the special relationship list **AssignableFrom** exist.

Comment: Believe it or not, generic type *definitions* do not have any implementation. The implementation is compiled only when you specify the type parameter, and only for that type (although implementations for reference types can be re-used because all pointers are the same size, but that is just an implementation detail). So you see to ask whether `List<>` implements `IEnumerable<>` doesn't make much sense because it has no implementation to begin with.

Comment: `@Jevgeni Geurtsen think the special relationship list AssignableFrom exist.` Oh but it is most definitely there in the *framework code*, so the relation exists, but as long as it doesn't have a concrete implementation, its useless, as John Wu pointed out.