# When does Type.Namespace return null if instance represents a generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net

Documentation of `Type.Namespace` property states:

> If the current Type represents a constructed generic type, this property returns the
> namespace that contains the generic type definition. Similarly, **if the current Type represents a generic parameter T**, this property returns the namespace that contains the generic type definition that defines T.
>
> **If the current Type object represents a generic parameter**, this property returns null.

When does `Type.Namespace` return null if instance represents a generic parameter like in the last cited paragraph? Or is the documentation wrong and the the statements in bold are actually contradicting each other?

To investigate I wrote some simple code, but I haven't found any answer. All the `Console.WriteLine` statements print something.

```
using System;

namespace TypeDemo
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var g = new G<int>();
            g.M(4);

            Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<>).Namespace);
        }
    }

    public class G<T>
    {
        static G()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Namespace);
        }

        public G()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Namespace);
            Console.WriteLine(GetType().Namespace);
        }

        public void M<S>(S s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(S).Namespace);
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetType().Namespace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670901/in-c-when-does-type-fullname-return-null?rq=1

Comment: _"All the Console.WriteLine statements print something."_ Well, they print also null, so they behave like documented. But you're right, the two paragraphs are confusing, especially the "generic parameter" in the last.

Comment: @TimSchmelter On what platform and under what conditions "they print **also** null" in my code sample? For me, and also suggested by the following answer they don't, at least on Windows. Is it possible to be different implementation between platforms? I really doublt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs are contradicting, but correct in principle. `Type.Namespace` returns null when the namespace is not available from generic definition. One way to get this is MakeGenericMethodParameter:

```
Type t=Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0);
Console.WriteLine("IsGenericParameter: "+t.IsGenericParameter);
Console.WriteLine("Namespace: "+(t.Namespace==null?"(null)":t.Namespace));
```

Another is to have a custom Type implementation (it's an abstract class everyone could derive from and override properties to do whatever they want).

**Edit:** [Type.Namespace docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.namespace?view=net-5.0) were fixed in PR https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/7466/files

Comment: "contradicting, but correct in principle" sounds like an oxymoron to me... As far as I can see, it is still the first paragraph that is correct (?), and perhaps it could be worded better by adding "and null when `T` is not in a generic definition".

Answer (score 4):

Note that all the types that you are printing are *not* generic parameters. Notice how when the methods are run, the type is already constructed. For example, when you do:

```
var g = new G<int>();

// which calls...
public G()
{
    // T has become "int" here!
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Namespace);
    Console.WriteLine(GetType().Namespace);
}
```

To get a `Type` that represents generic parameters, you can:

> [call] the `GetGenericArguments` method of a `Type` object that represents a generic type definition, or the `GetGenericArguments` method of a `MethodInfo` object that represents a generic method definition.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenericparameter?view=net-5.0#remarks)

For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo.C<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].Namespace);

namespace Foo {
    class C<T> {
        public void Foo() {
            
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo.C).GetMethod("Foo").GetGenericArguments()[0].Namespace);

namespace Foo {
    class C {
        public void Foo<T>() {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Both of them prints `Foo`, and I have not been able to find a case where a generic type parameter is in a namespace, but its `Namespace` returns null. This means the actual behaviour matches this sentence:

> Similarly, if the current Type represents a generic parameter T, this property returns the namespace that contains the generic type definition that defines T.

Comment: I actually think it's a bug, because an unconstructed (open) type parameter has no fully-qualified name (`AssemblyQualifiedName` and `FullName` return `null`), so `Namespace` should also be `null`

Comment: @Charlieface That does make sense. I’m not sure which behaviour is intended right now. I think what might have happened was, the intended behaviour changed at some point, and they only changed part of the docs, and also possibly forgot to change the implementation (?)

Comment: Charlieface and Sweeper both provided valuable insight, which I used to raise [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/7340) via GitHub. There is definitely something wrong with formulating the remarks in the docs.